# Matlab convert DCM to BMP

Tags: matlab, image-processing

How to convert `.dcm`(dicom) image to `.bmp` format.

I have tried this, but its not working for me.

`000000.dcm` is a medical lung image (size 6 MB)

```
 dcmimg = dicomread('000000.dcm');
>> imshow(dcmimg);
```

DCM image read in `dcmimg`

```
imwrite(dcmimg, 'myfile.bmp');
```

**Getting error:**

```
Error using writebmp (line 15)
Expected X to be one of these types:

  logical, uint8, single, double

Instead its type was uint16.

Error in imwrite (line 477)
        feval(fmt_s.write, data, map, filename, paramPairs{:});
```

I am not understanding these errors, What's going wrong. Help me out, Thank You.

Comment: [Numeric data types in MATLAB](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/numeric-types.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dicom uses unsigned 16 bit integers. The function that writes .bmp files expects a different data type, as explained by the error message. This suggests that the following should work:

```
imwrite(double(dcmimg), 'myFile.bmp');
```

By explicitly converting the data type to `double` you should get rid of the error. Actually `single` might be enough... It too can represent 16 bit integers without loss of precision.

Comment: thank @Floris it worked but giving me `blank` image on reading it. Although it has size.

Comment: Blank image eh? Can you try to display the image before saving to file with `imscale(double(dcmimg))`? Perhaps there is a scaling problem.